# i am confused in a small concepts

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am very new to VBscript and learning hard all the concepts. During my practice I am stuck with a doubt.

```
dim a,b,c
set a = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 'initiate the file system object'
set b = a.GetFolder("E:\test") 'returns a object . and for the instance that varaiable b refers to that returned object'
c = b.datecreated 'accesing and storing the property to a variable /C/'
msgbox "folder: " &c
```

When I execute this there is no error message and it works fine. But when I change

`c = b.datecreated` TO `set c = b.datecreated` than

it shows this error:

```
> object required:'datecreated'
```

I know it's a basic thing but some time small things make you learn a lot and helpful for future.

Answer (score 5):

The  keyword `Set` is used in VBScript only for assignment of objects:

```
set a = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
```

Non-objects - like the creation date - are assigned without `Set`.

```
c = b.datecreated
```

(This is my favorite nastiness of VBScript.)

Comment: ... there is quite a list to chose from!

Comment: For me the problem is not so much with the inconsistency, but the lack of documentation - users are just supposed to know these little quirks by word of mouth.

Comment: My favorite nastiness is to make objects with a default method without arguments like `Public Default Function Value() ' as String` in it. It seems a clever move at the time you create such a method, but in the end you'll always need to look up what things like `MyDictionary.Add objectWithDefaultFunction` do.