# Count the shapes in word document using visual basic script

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, ms-office

I wanted to count all the shapes in certain word document using word macros using this code

```
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\Test.docx")
Set var1 = objWord.ActiveDocument
Set var2 = var1.Shapes
Set var3 = var2.Count
```

but I get this error when executing the script

"at line 7 - Error: Object required: var2.Count"

What is wrong with this ?

Comment: .Count is a simple variable, not an object - so drop the `Set` before `var3`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053412/603855

Comment: See [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Comment: when I removed Set keyword, I get an error which is "Count is not a method"


My question is how to show this count in a message box or in command line ?

Comment: Try `WScript.Echo objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count`.